# My section div is going on top of my header div

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I have 3 main sections to the site I'm practising on: Nav, Header and Section.
My header bar contains an image with some text in the middle, I spent a long time trying to find how to allow the image to accept the text on top of it and then have it go straight in to the centre(both vertically and horizontally) of the img.

I found something that worked, but after finding that solution, my Section decided to also go on top of the image, which I'm certain it is because of the `position: absolute;` on the image.

The help I need; how do I get the section to go under the header, with keeping the piece of text on top of the image and in the centre of it?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: orange;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#bannerImage {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
section {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <img id="logo" src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/f607af5bc60d1b2837add83c70a2aa45/tumblr_inline_mrwv19q8fE1qz4rgp.gif" />
    <li><a href="Game1.html" id="myBtn" onclick="disableLink()">Game 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Game 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Game 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header>
  <img id="bannerImage" src="http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Hogwarts-lake.png" />
  <h1>Codewarts</h1> 
</header>

<section>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Do you have a name?.....Great!</p>
    <p>Insert it in the box below!</p>


  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want display:table for your header? Id try removing it and setting a min-width for it.

Comment: It is what I found online on how to align a text dead in the middle on a image.

Comment: Try setting a min height* (sorry not width.) to the header.

Comment: Yup that has done the trick. I inserted the min-height and matched it with the height of the image (500px), deleted the display: table stuff. But, the section moved below which is good, but the image moved to the left with the text overlapping it whilst the text was sitting in the center, so I re added the display: table stuff and it corrected the whole thing.  If that is valid, what I have done, thanks, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do You want something like this? [image: this]

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}
header h1 { 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50% )
}
```

Comment: This area is for answers, not comments or questions for the poster.

Comment: Yes, but I've already found the solution, see above under the comment section for my question.